Azure traffic manager endpoint
I need solution to add the Kubernetes services inside the Traffic manager using terraform and in order to do that I need to have a public IP address for each cluster
Traffic Manager Profile
Traffic Manager Profile Resource
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_profile" "converse_traffic_manager" {         
  name = "converse-traffic-manager"                                             
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name                      
                                                                                
  traffic_routing_method = "Weighted"                                           
                                                                                
  dns_config {                                                                  
    relative_name = "converse-dns"                                              
    ttl           = 100                                                         
  }                                                                             
                                                                                
  monitor_config {                                                              
    protocol                     = "HTTP"                                       
    port                         = 7891                                         
    path                         = "/health"                                    
    interval_in_seconds          = 30                                           
    timeout_in_seconds           = 9                                            
    tolerated_number_of_failures = 3                                            
  }                                                                             
}                                                                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint" "converse_service_ep" {       
  name = "converse-service-ep"                                                  
  profile_id        = azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.converse_traffic_manager.id
  target_resource_id = (tolist(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_wc1.network_profile.0.load_balancer_profile.0.effective_outbound_ips)[0])
  weight = 1                                                                    
}


I get following error
│ Error: creating Endpoint Type (Subscription: "0def0707-b37a-42ae-8174-xxxxx"
│ Traffic Manager Profile Name: "converse-traffic-manager"
│ Endpoint Type: "AzureEndpoints"
│ Endpoint Name: "converse-service-ep"): unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: BadRequest: The resource '/subscriptions/0def0707-b37a-42ae-8174-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/node-rg-k8s-stg-use1-az-cnv-01/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/ff18c553-9ab4-4500-a00a-1a62a347d720' specified by the targetResourceId for endpoint 'converse-service-ep' does not have a DNS name.
If I replace the target_resource_id with following statement
"/subscriptions/0def0707-b37a-42ae-8174-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/node-rg-k8s-stg-use1-az-cnv-01/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/ConverseLoadBalancerPublicIp",
then endpoint is added successfully


Referring Azure AKS with Traffic Manager Using Static Public IPs in Terraform

The problem seems to be the way you directly refering Azure Traffic Manager endpoint with AKS Ip doesnt have dns name by default while creating the cluster which causes the blocker.

For the cluster to enable the dns for IP

Configuration:
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_profile" "traffic_manager" {
  name                = "tm-demo-profile"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name

  traffic_routing_method = "Weighted"

  dns_config {
    relative_name = "nginxtmvk"
    ttl           = 100
  }

  monitor_config {
    protocol                     = "HTTP"
    port                         = 80
    path                         = "/"
    interval_in_seconds          = 30
    timeout_in_seconds           = 10
    tolerated_number_of_failures = 3
  }
}

resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint" "nginx_endpoint" {
  name               = "nginx-endpoint"
  profile_id         = azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.traffic_manager.id
  target_resource_id = "ID of the IP created by cluster"
  weight             = 1
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/quickstart-create-traffic-manager-profile-terraform?tabs=azure-cli
azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry

have you got the chance to review the solution provided? Is there anything I can do on my end to assist further? @neeraj310
